# How do I bind webmin to the 127.0.0.1 address?

Tags: security, webmin

How do I bind webmin to the localhost address?

I'd like to be able to do this so that I can secure all the admin services on my TurnKey Linux machine by binding all of them to the localhost address `127.0.0.1` and only allow them to be accessed via local port forwarding in an SSH secured environment with a passphrase protected public key file.  All of this (including SSH) will be only on one server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either can change/add in /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf the allow directive to put there

```
allow=127.0.0.1
```

or change it to be called from xinetd, changing inetd=0 to inetd=1. Calling it from inetd uses up less memory, albeit it is slower. Ideal only for situations where you need xinetd for something else too, and you rarely use it.

xinetd for it would be:

```
service webmin
{
    user = root
    env = LANG=
    port = 10000
    socket_type = stream
    protocol = tcp
    wait = no
    disable = no
    type = UNLISTED
    server = /usr/share/webmin/miniserv.pl
    server_args = /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf
    only_from = 127.0.0.1
}
```